# How to handle this TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, shutil

I am trying to copy some specific files from one folder to other by giving name list of files , its giving type error , where i am wrong in this code

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

src = "D:/folder2"
dst = "D:/folder1"

files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) if ('7809.txt','988876.txt') in i and path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(path.join(src, f), dst)
```

Comment: `('7809.txt','988876.txt') in i` is illegal. `i` is a string. You cannot check is a tuple is a member of a string. What exactly did you want to check?

Comment: @DYZ  I have list of files name ('7809.txt','988876.txt') i want to check if these files available in Src folder copy these files to dst folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the order of operands:

```
files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) 
         if i in ('7809.txt', '988876.txt') 
         and path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
```

The `ispath()` check is not necessary: unless you are doing something weird, `"{src}/7809.txt"` is already a file, not a directory or something else. So, you can use a set intersection instead of a list comprehension:

```
files = set(os.listdir(src)) & {'7809.txt', '988876.txt'}
```